# MySQL REGEXP word boundary detection with german umlauts when using BINARY Operator

Tags: mysql, regex, character-set

I made a strange discovery. If I execute the following SQL-Command:

SELECT 'Konzessionäre' REGEXP '[[:<:]]Konzession[[:>:]]'

it gives me the result - as expected - 0

But if I do the same together with the BINARY operator:

SELECT BINARY 'Konzessionäre' REGEXP '[[:<:]]Konzession[[:>:]]'

the result ist 1, so I think there is a MySQL problem with the regexp word boundary detection and german umlauts (like here the "ä") in conjunction with the BINARY Operator. As another example I can do this query:

SELECT BINARY 'Konzessionsäre' REGEXP '[[:<:]]Konzession[[:>:]]'

So here the result is 0 - as I would expect. So how can I solve this? Is this probably a bug in MySQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By casting your string as `BINARY` you have stripped its associated character set property. So it's unclear how the word-boundary pattern should match. I'd guess it matches only ASCII values A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and also _.

When casting the string as `BINARY`, MySQL knows nothing about any other higher character values that also should be considered alphanumeric, because which characters should be alphanumeric depends on the character set.

I guess you are using `BINARY` to make this a case-sensitive regular expression search. Apparently, this has the unintended consequence of spoiling the word-boundary pattern-match.

You should not use `BINARY` in this comparison. You could do a secondary comparison to check for case-sensitive matching, but not with word boundaries.

```
SELECT (BINARY 'Konzessionäre' REGEXP 'Konzession') AND ('Konzessionäre' REGEXP '[[:<:]]Konzession[[:>:]]')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I solved this now by using another Collation. This one works:

 `SELECT BINARY 'Konzessionäre' REGEXP '[[:<:]]Konzession[[:>:]]' COLLATE utf8_bin`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's REGEXP works with bytes, not characters.  So, in `CHARACTER SET utf8`, `ä` is 2 bytes.  It is unclear what the definition of "word boundary" in such a situation.

Recent versions of MariaDB have a better regexp engine.